# Should I check in large model file to git repository?

Tags: git

I am creating machine learning model files, which can be several GB in size. It takes time to check in them into repository. Is it good practice to check in those files into repository? The fact is that, those model files have to be an integrated part of the application. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need that file versioned then you most likely are looking for Git LFS: https://git-lfs.github.com/

> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio
>   samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git,
>   while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or
>   GitHub Enterprise.

But if it does not change that much, then perhaps just make it downloadable

Comment: Is Git LFS commerical?

Comment: seen the website I linked to?

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do it though. If the model files are truly large (I assume neural networks?!) another way may be to use something like a configuration file that points to a specific place on the production server, where that model is stored.
You can then either copy the model files by hand (if models are not updated on a daily basis) or write a script that does it for you if you want to update your deployed models.
Then, you can store the configuration file in the git repo (very small) but you still define the specific model.